# How to get the referenced node id in a webform?

Tags: nodes, webforms

I have a webform that is connected to a node in drupal 8. When the webform loads from the node link I need to get the source entity id from url.
How can I achieve that in my custom module? the url is as follows:
https://example.com/en/form/edu-form?source_entity_type=node&source_entity_id=134

I tried the following but I get an error:

```
 $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('source_entity_id');
 $nodeId = $node->id();
```

And also this (I tried to get the node id from the webform object)

```
/** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformRequestInterface $request_handler */
$request_handler = \Drupal::service('webform.request');
$source_entity = $request_handler->getCurrentSourceEntity('webform');
$node_id=$source_entity->id;
```

Comment: You set `$node` equal to the `source_entity_id` and then try to access it like it's an object, but it's just an id. Also, you should include your error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the webform's source entity id can be prepopulated via a URL and the below code should work using `$source_entity->id()` instead of `$source_entity->id`

```
/** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformRequestInterface $request_handler */
$request_handler = \Drupal::service('webform.request');
$source_entity = $request_handler->getCurrentSourceEntity('webform');
$node_id = $source_entity->id();
```

[image]